# how do you sum an Array that is declared as a switch in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am new to Java and building an Android app using it, I want to be able to determine how many switches are on but not sure how the best way to sum an array of switches. I currently have:

```
SS = new Switch[8];
SS[0] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch1);
SS[1] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch2);
SS[2] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch3);
SS[3] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch4);
SS[4] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch5);
SS[5] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch6);
SS[6] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch7);
SS[7] = getView().findViewById(R.id.switch8);

submit = getView().findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick (View v) {
        totalactive= IntStream.of(SS).sum();
```

with the array "SS" declared as a class global.

Thank you

Comment: SS is not compatible with IntStream.of() -- how do you tell if a "Switch" is "on" or "off" - is there a method you can call?

Comment: I was just messing with you buddy, don't mind me ;-)

Comment: I use an setOnCheckedChangeListener for each switch but want to limit how many they can turn on at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `onClick` use a `for each` loop:

```
totalactive = 0;
for (Switch s : SS) {
    if (s.isChecked()) totalactive++;
}
```

Comment: int total = SS.stream().filter(s -> s.isChecked).count();

Comment: @DavidZimmerman array doesn't have stream() method, count() returns `long` =)

Comment: long total = Arrays.stream(SS).filter(s -> s.isChecked).count();

Comment: This solution worked great, thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far are great! But then, you could also do it the old school way:

```
int totalactive = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < SS.length; i++){
    if(SS[i].isChecked()){
        totalactive++;
    }
}

//Here's your result:
Log.d("sumTotal", Integer.toString(totalactive));
```

I bet this is very easy to understand and relate to. I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: This is very reminiscent of C and what I was about to fall back on but I went with the other simply because it looked cleaner. I am sure this works as well though, thank you for the advice.